# Can a pan flute or horn be played one-handed?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard

I've been through the PHB and DMG and not been able to find any specific rules for this. Clearly the string instruments must be played two-handed, but I don't see why my bard couldn't be playing the pan flute or horn in one hand (as a focus for his bardic spells) and wielding a weapon or shield in his other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pan flutes vary in size, as a simple Google image search reveals.  Depending on the style, it might require one or two hands.  A simple 4 or 5 pipe flute is certainly designed for single hand use, while a 20 pipe flute may not be reasonable to use in a single hand.  In extreme circumstances, you might even argue it [occupies a shield slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iBBO.jpg).

Comment: *gasp* My pan flute could be incorporated into my shield! Like that battle-axe/guitar I saw.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding horns, I have successfully played my trumpet with only one hand many times, and I am not a superhuman adventurer!

Answer (score 1):

If you can [play with no hands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_flute#/media/File:Dom_Flemons_of_the_Carolina_Chocolate_Drops.jpg), you should be able to play with one hand.

Comment: I've been playing with a drum and shawm around the neck of my dwarf, while wading into battle with a battleaxe. Inspired by these types of musicians.