# If a bard has two instruments can they cast regularly still?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, feats, bard, stacking

If a bard, say has War Caster, and has two magical instruments, like say the Rhythm Maker's Drum, and a Reveler's Concertina, can they cast spells that have somatic parts?

I had a player ask, and wanted a more clear ruling than what I could give.

Comment: Are they holding one instrument in each hand? And if so…why?

Comment: The question of whether one instrument is strapped to their body somehow, or if both are in their hands, seems highly related to whether they have a free hand or not to perform somatic components.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Yes, as long as the spell has a non-costly material component.

The War Caster feat actually doesn't help here, since it states:

> You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands.

Since the instruments are not weapons or shields, War Caster doesn't change anything.

The rest is complicated, so I'll put a quick-reference table here first, then explain the rules afterward. The "*" in the first slot is the Verbal component; it doesn't actually matter for this question.

| Components Required | Can you cast it with two instruments in hand? |
| --- | --- |
| (*,S) | No |
| (*,S,M) where M has a cost | No |
| (*,S,M) where M does not have a cost | Yes |
| (V) | Yes |

Now, there are three relevant rules we need to look at; the rule for Somatic Components:

> Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures. If a spell requires a somatic component, *the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.*

And the rule for Material Components:

> A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell’s material components — or to hold a spellcasting focus — but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

*If* the particular spell has *both* Somatic and Material components, then *a hand that is holding a spellcasting focus can satisfy both*. So as long as it is (*,S,M) spell, you do not actually need a free hand as long as at least one of your hands is holding the spellcasting focus, unless the Material component is a costly component, since the rules for focuses state:

> A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in chapter 5, “Equipment”) in place of the components specified for a spell. *But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.*

If the Material component has a cost, it cannot be replaced by the spellcasting focus and you must have a free hand to handle the component.

*However*, if the spell has a Somatic component and *no* Material component, *then the caster must have a properly free hand to cast the spell*, since Somatic components require a free hand unless the spell also has a material component and the hand is being used for that component too.

It should be noted that [the rules do not require the bard to actually play the instrument used as a focus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79549/62294), so this work *rules as written*, but I have played with a DM that would not have allowed this because he required the bard to play the instrument when casting.

Comment: "since Somatic components require a free hand unless the spell also has a material component and the hand is being used for that component too" - could you quote a rule to support this? None of your existing quotes seem to cover it.

Comment: Your quotes say that a caster can use the same free hand to perform somatic components and access material components (or hold a focus), but they don't say you can use a non-free hand to perform somatic components if you're using that hand for material components. The rules say the hand still has to be free.

Comment: (Or alternatively, if you consider a hand holding a focus to be free, it doesn't seem like these quotes support *only* considering the hand free if you're using the focus to replace material components.)

Comment: @user2357112 A hand holding a focus can provide the S and M component for a (S,M) spell, it’s my second quote: “A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell’s material components — or to hold a spellcasting focus — **but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.**”

Comment: That doesn't relax the requirement for the hand to be free. I would interpret that quote as either saying that the hand has to be free to hold the focus for the material components and release the focus to perform somatic components, or saying that a hand holding a focus is considered free enough to perform somatic components, and in the second case, I don't see anything that would support only considering the hand free if you're using the focus to replace material components.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay. It seems pretty straightforward to me. There’s nothing else I can say about it.

Comment: it is pretty straight foreward tbh

Comment: @Morthanal That’s good to hear, as you are the person I most hoped to help understand.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I appreciate it, surprised the player tbh, he thought it was gonna be a no and hes now gonna be doing it rest of game

Answer (score -2):

Since Warcaster affects only weapons and shields, it does nothing for instruments. Bards must play their music to create magic, and playing their instruments requires two hands. There can only be one instrument held to cast magic. Rules aside, it's really dumb to imagine the bard holding two instruments and doing anything, magic or not. They have to use a free item action to stow one instrument, and then another free item interaction next turn to pull out the other instrument. Or, they can drop the first instrument and pull the second instrument on the same turn. However, as DM you could allow something inventive like leather straps that keep the instruments on the body so when 'dropped' they don't fall to the ground. I'd say someone with leather working proficiency needs to make the straps.

Comment: “it's really dumb to imagine the bard holding two instruments and doing anything” [20th level bard Michaelangelo Batio would like a word](https://youtu.be/rutyA12z3Ok?si=kXCPWMRdxOoCpXO5)